# SQL query loop slowing over time

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a database stored locally and am using Excel to get small tables from it, which I then process, format etc and save as flat files. There are about 7,000 files I need from it.

The process starts off very fast, but over time it slows down and each file ends up taking about 10x the time of the first ones. Here is the loop:

```
        For i = firstrow + 1 To lastrow

    RemoveConnections
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'Get annual data

        Sheets("data").Cells.Delete
        sqlstring1 = "SELECT [compnumber],[mapcode],[amount],[reportd],[reportm],[reporty]  FROM [Mergent].[dbo].[Mastertable_proc]" & _
        "WHERE Compnumber = '" & Sheets("list").Cells(i, 1).Value & "' and reporttype='A';"
        connstring = _
        "ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=MY-PC;UID=Andy;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=DataM"
        With Sheets("data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Sheets("data").Range("a1"), Sql:=sqlstring1)
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

...

processes data and saves file

...

next i
```

The following Remove Connections macro is called at the start of each loop to drop all the existing connections:

```
Sub RemoveConnections()
Dim xConnect As Object
On Error Resume Next
For Each xConnect In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
xConnect.Delete
Next xConnect
For Each listobj In Sheets("data").ListObjects
listobj.Delete
Next listobj
End Sub
```

I'm fairly sure the processing itself and saving files isn't the problem, as I can run the macro without it all and it still slows over time.

Anyone have any ideas why this is slowing down? I notice that SQLserver.exe takes up more and more RAM on my computer as time goes by, but I am still well within my maximum when it slows, but it tells me I'm doing something wrong in the loop like not closing a connection or something.

I have also tried a version which edits a single connection in each loop, so doesn't create a new one each time, yet it still slows over time and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the slowdown is caused by connecting to/disconnecting from the database 7000 times... Is it possible to run the query once to pull the entire Mastertable_proc into Excel and then use a loop to process and save each unique Compnumber?

Comment: No unfortunately not, the database is 100 million rows. Im not sure it is the constant connections, because if I use the workbook for 7000 files it ends up really slow and never speeds up again. but if I paste all the code into a new workbook and run it fresh, then it goes back to being very fast. So I think there is something Im not deleting after each connection that is slowing it all down.